# Any built-in react modules like ReactTable,react-router etc are not working in my react app. How I can solve it? T

Tags: reactjs, npm

I import 'ReactTable,react-router' modules in my app. But error displays on console that : 'Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.' and visual studio code displays "successfully compiled".
This is the code of package.json file: `

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "cra-template": "1.0.3",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-table": "^7.2.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
`
```

Comment: Did you install all of required modules with `npm i`?

Comment: Can you share your package.json file? Also check if you have the following packages llisted in the Package.json file. If yes , then try running the command `npm i` or `yarn`

Comment: my package.json file has react-table.When I use it it shows an error -  react-dom.development.js:23965 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

Comment: You forgot to export your component somewhere in your code. This has nothing to do with package.json

Comment: I export my component with this line --   "export default App;"